# ArrayList avalible everywhere in the project

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, retrofit2

I am looking to implement ArrayList that is avalible everywhere in the project. I want to dynamicly add, delete elements, etc. of this ArrayList and finally send it via Retrofit.

Any solution?

Comment: You could always pass the ArrayList in the Bundle when you go from Activity to Activity.

Comment: Yes but i want to add elements in Recycler View Adapter

Comment: An option is a persisted database that can be accessed/updated from anywhere in your application - its more initial work, but better than passing arraylists in bundles (which can quite quickly hit the Binder limit)

Comment: I am thinking about ArrayList with few positions but I want to display elements in other activity and there add or remove some elements before send this arraylist via retrofit

Comment: OK, well you've been given 2 viable suggestions .. using bundles to pass your Arraylist or using a database .. pick one (if you've only have a few elements and you don't care about keeping them use a bundle)!

Comment: Ok but what about situation where i pass this ArrayList  by Bundle to other Activity (there remove some elements) and decide to come back and add new elements... Then i should pass it via Bundle again?

Comment: Well use a database then? You should really state your use cases in the question, not just add "what if's" later...

Answer (score -3):

You can declare your array as static :

```
public static  List<String> myArray =  new ArrayList<>();
```

You can access it from anywhere

```
myArray.add("test");
```

Comment: Whilst you *can* do this you really shouldn't.  Global mutable objects attract bugs like the moon attracts moths.  Use the database.

Comment: This ArrayList will have just few elements. You think database will be the best solution?